# random forest and prediction

Tags: predictive-models, random-forest, error

I am building a random forest model to make predictions.

Response variable is treated as continuous but not really continuous, e.g., integers from 0 to 10.

I have problems in constructing prediction interval for new observation.

Here are my questions:

1. If prediction error is not normally distributed, can I use mean+sd to calculate prediction interval?
2. When I examine the relationship between prediction error and response, it looks like small response are overestimated and large response are underestimated. Is it always like this in random forest model? How to correct the prediction bias?
3. Since I have constraints for possible response values (0 to 10), is there any way to incorporate the constraints in prediction?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated.  This is a good question. I've spaced it out a bit to make it easier to read, and added a couple more tags to attract a bit more attention.

Comment: Have you tried making a 11-class classification?

Comment: If you're using package randomForest you should look into the corr.bias term in the function to potentially help correct prediction bias. .